# How to use GDPopt properly?

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to solve a multi-objective GDP in Pyomo.The problem is GDP, because my decision variables are semi-continuous.

```
def off_rule(d, i):
    m = d.model()
    d.c = Constraint(expr=model.x[i] == 0)

model.disjunct_off = Disjunct(Set, rule=off_rule)

def disyuncion_encendido_rule(d, i):
    m = d.model()
    d.c = Constraint(expr=inequality(LB[i], model.x[i], UB[i]))
model.disjunct_on = Disjunct(Set, rule=on_rule)

def ConjuntoDisyunciones_rule(m, i):
    return[model.disjunct_off[i], model.disjunct_on[i]]
model.ConjuntoDisyunciones = Disjunction(Set, rule=ConjuntoDisyunciones_rule)
```

To solve it, I am using the weights method.

I have defined my objectives such that:

```
model.obj1 = Objective(expr = Objective1)
model.obj2 = Objective(expr = Objective2)
model.obj3 = Objective(expr = Objective3)
model.obj4 = Objective(expr = Objective4)
model.obj5 = Objective(expr = Objective5)
```

Objective1 and the other Objective are Python variables containing a Pyomo expression.

```
<pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr.SumExpression at 0x27497156740>
```

Then I create a general objective and add all the objectives with their corresponding weight.

```
model.obj_total = Objective(expr = 0)
model.obj_total.expr += LAMBDA1*model.obj1
model.obj_total.expr += LAMBDA2*model.obj2
model.obj_total.expr += LAMBDA3*model.obj3
model.obj_total.expr += LAMBDA4*model.obj4
model.obj_total.expr += LAMBDA5*model.obj5
```

I then deactivate the individual objectives

```
model.obj1.deactivate() 
model.obj2.deactivate() 
model.obj3.deactivate()  
model.obj4.deactivate()  
model.obj5.deactivate()
```

And it is now that one of my doubts arises.
How do I configure the solver call? Since one of my objectives is quadratics.I have tried:

```
results = SolverFactory('gdpopt.loa').solve(
model, mip_solver='gurobi', nlp_solver = 'ipopt')
```

Is this expression correct?

The solver seems to run, as it finds a solution, but while doing so I get the following warning messages:

```
WARNING: Discrete problem was unbounded. Re-solving with arbitrary bound
values of (-1e+15, 1e+15) on the objective, in order to get a discrete
solution. Check your initialization routine.
 WARNING: Unsupported expression type for FBBT: <class
'pyomo.core.base.objective.ScalarObjective'>. Bounds will not be improved
in this part of the tree.
WARNING: Unsupported expression type for FBBT: <class
'pyomo.core.base.objective._GeneralObjectiveData'>. Bounds will not be
improved in this part of the tree.
WARNING: Unsupported expression type for FBBT: <class
'pyomo.core.base.objective._GeneralObjectiveData'>. Bounds will not be
improved in this part of the tree.
WARNING: Unsupported expression type for FBBT: <class
'pyomo.core.base.objective._GeneralObjectiveData'>. Bounds will not be
improved in this part of the tree.
 WARNING: Unsupported expression type for FBBT: <class
'pyomo.core.base.objective._GeneralObjectiveData'>. Bounds will not be
improved in this part of the tree.
WARNING: Unsupported expression type for FBBT: <class
'pyomo.core.base.objective.ScalarObjective'>. Bounds will not be improved
in this part of the tree.
WARNING: Unsupported expression type for FBBT: <class
'pyomo.core.base.objective.ScalarObjective'>. Bounds will not be improved
in this part of the tree.
```

I don't understand why it tells me that my problem is unbounded, when in defining my decision variables, I have defined the limits with a rule.

```
def initials_bounds_rule(model,i):
    return(0,Bounds[i])

model.x = Var(Set, bounds = initials_bounds_rule)
```

I also don't understand why the message *Unsupported expression type for FBBT appears*.
What is going on?

So in short, my questions are:

is the solver well named?

Why do I get these warning messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting Pyomo `Objective` objects into the expression tree when you define `obj_total`. The warnings from FBBT should go away if you instead construct its expression with:

```
model.obj_total.expr += LAMBDA1*model.obj1.expr
```

(and so on for the others.)

Regarding the discrete problem being unbounded, it would be helpful if you could provide a minimal example. You are correct that if all your variables are bounded, then you should not be getting that particular warning: The bounds should be in the discrete problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @Emma. All error messages including the one about the bounds have disappeared by redefining the total target wit model.obj_total.expr += LAMBDA1*model.obj1.expr